# Url with HTTP is not detecting in my web app(which is running on HTTPS) at IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, internet-explorer

I'm working on DSS Digital Signature in my web app which should detect whether NexU(Desktop app running on a client machine) at some point.

It is working fine if my web app URL is with HTTP but not with HTTPS in IE Browser.  In chrome, it is working fine in both the cases.
The following is js code which is written to detect the NexU.

```
// IE
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position){
    return this.substr(position || 0, searchString.length) === searchString;
   };
}

 $.get("http://localhost:9795/nexu-info", function(data) {
     // something responded
     alert('success...'+JSON.stringify(data));
 }).fail(function(data) {
     // no response, NexU not installed or not started
      alert('fail...'+JSON.stringify(data));
 });
```

I'm getting the following error when the app is running in IE browser

[image]

What changes I have to made here to working this in IE browser?
My application is developed with Spring Framework.

Thanks

Sree

Answer (score 1):

If the reason is due to mixed content security warning you can use protocol relative url and browser will send to same protocol that the page is opened in

```
$.get("//localhost:9795/nexu-info", function(data) {....
```

Comment: I can't ask my client to run NexU in HTTPS protocol. It is working fine in Chrome with different protocols but not in IE. I need to fix this from my end

Comment: A protocol relative url doesn't force user to change anything.  Inspect the actual request in dev tools network for more debugging detail as well as error in console. Those alerts as you have shown are not very helpful